# JSON Data formatting issue

Tags: json, dataset

My json data being retrieved is as of below, notice that the format is not right in terms of object and key values why is this so, I am retrieving this json data from a dataset using the jayrock rpc service for asp.net 3.5

```
{
   "Table":{
      "columns":[
         "i_member_id",
         "i_group_id",
         "u_name",
         "u_tel",
         "u_email",
         "u_password",
         "d_timestamp",
         "b_activated"
      ],
      "rows":[
         [
            1,
            0,
            "kevin",
            "1231234",
            "kevin@creaworld.com.sg",
            "123",
            "2011-01-05T09:51:36.8730000+08:00",
            true
         ],
         [
            2,
            0,
            "kevin2",
            "asdads",
            "kevin2@creaworld.com.sg",
            "123123",
            "2011-01-05T10:01:46.1530000+08:00",
            true
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: You say, "notice that the format is not right".  What's not right about it?  It looks fine.

Comment: This is list of objects and Table have list of objects and remain column, rows have a list of array.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the data posted in the question - I've just checked it with JSONLint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the link is to find the json formater
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Better you can use third party DLL

[Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

It will use full for you.